# Display Issue Runas /user:administrator

Tags: windows-7, runas

I have a strange issue with a software that I'm having to run as local administrator.

When I launch the application normally it is fine. When I launch the application using runas /user:administrator it ends up with these black lines across the application.

This causes the user to be unable to see half the content in the application.

I've tried all the compatibility settings in the .exe properties to no joy.

The program is 32 bit running in Windows 7 32 bit.

Any thoughts on where to begin to troubleshoot.

Comment: What is the name of the program? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: It's an old legacy software we use at work not something well known. I'll try to take a screenshot of the problem I'm experiencing.